# How to extract ID from string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

I got a string

```
var str = "javascript:DeleteCountryConfirm(191)";
```

and I need to have the ID 191 in a variable. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it's actually a string like this:

```
var str = "javascript:DeleteCountryConfirm(191);"
```

You can do this:

```
var id = parseInt(str.match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
```

Or:

```
var id = parseInt(str.replace(/[^0-9-]/, ''), 10)
```